# Integrating Apache and Restlet server like Apache and Tomcat

Tags: apache, http, restlet

I have my Apache http server running on localhost:80 and restlet server on localhost:8182, but I want to configure above combination just like Apache http server and Apache tomcat servlet container can be configured with mod_jk library.

Is it possible?

Do I have to modify code of mod_jk for this purpose.

Please advice!!!

Thanks in advance!!

Ashish

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Unable to do this as of now, Using Apache Tomcat only as servlet container.

Answer (score 1):

There are two options:

- Setting your Restlet server connector with Protocol.AJP (for use with mod_jk or mod_proxy_ajp), which works with the Jetty connector.
- Using mod_proxy as a reverse proxy to your Restlet connector (with Protocol.HTTP).